# How add dimensions[0] of selected objects?

Tags: python, scripting

I need to add all the x axis dimension of the selected objects in my scene.

I try with

```
for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    dim = i.dimensions[0]
    dimX = sum(dim[:])
```

The sum command don't work, dim isn't a list. 
How can i do that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite `dim` and `dimX` in every iteration of your loop, you do not add something to a list.

If you need a list of all dimensions you can use

```
dim = []
for i in bpy.context.selected_objects :
    dim.append(i.dimensions[0])
dimX = sum(dim[:])
```

`dim` will then contain all dimensions and `dimX` will contain the sum. `dim` is initialized as an empty list and the loop appends the dimensions to it. Note the indentation of the last line: `dimX` needs to be on the same height as `for`, otherwise python will think that it belongs to the for loop and execute it in every iteration.

If you just want the sum of the x dimensions you can add them up into a variable that you initialized with 0 first:

```
dimX = 0
for i in bpy.context.selected_objects :
    dimX += i.dimensions[0]
```